# HTTPS except one page

Tags: php, ssl, https, http, apache2

Im trying to configure my apache server to host everything in https except one page that i need my script to be able to access. Currently i am prompted for to bypass the untrusted ssl certificate which is ruining my automation. Here is the SSL configuration in my current 000-default.conf file.

```
Redirect permanent "/" "https://<ip>/word.php/"
```

I've tried adding this line in the 000-default.conf file to rewrite a rule and it hasnt worked.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://<ip>/word.php [R,L]
```

I've tried everything and none of it seems to be working. I do not have a .htaccess file so please do not recommend that i modify that. Thanks for the help

Comment: +1 for not having a `.htaccess` file :)

Comment: The obvious solution if of course to either get a trusted TLS certificate (which nowadays are can be obtained for free with Let's Encrypt or for almost nominal amounts of money if you need longer validity or wild-cards) or to instruct your automation to NOT care about the status/validity of the TLS certificate that you use.

Comment: Where's your script running?  If on localhost, the other "obvious" solution is bind an HTTP instance localhost alone.

Comment: a) i already have set up SSL within my environment. This is going to private, so i really dont care if the cert is untrusted, i just need a solution for switching to http b) its Cross-object, not on localhost

Comment: Why is your script not able to access HTTPS content? You should take time to address this instead of changing your webserver configuration to accomodate this corner case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question as you are talking about a script then you say you are prompted to do something, so if it is a script why is there some manual intervention?

If you want your `RewriteRule` not to apply for one URL, you need to add a `RewriteCond` before it, to filter out the URL you need to be kept as pure HTTP.

Something like:

> RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!^/a_specific_page"

This would however apply to all accesses, not only those coming from your "script". If you want to discriminate that you will need to find something to identify your script access, like its source IP if this can be trusted, or some specific HTTP header, etc...